# Keep aspect ratio true to the mode

Tags: linux-mint, x11

I've recently installed Linux Mint 17, replacing my ageing Mint 13 installation. I've got a 16:9 screen. In case it matters, my graphics card is an NVidia GeForce 210.

Now back in Mint 13, if a game switched to a 4:3 mode, I got it displayed in the correct aspect ratio, with black bars left and right. However now they are deformed to fill the full screen, which is annoying because it not only looks terrible, but also destroys angles and therefore affects gameplay.

I then also checked explicitly switching to a 4:3 mode (using the "Monitors" settings dialog), and again it deformed the image. I also checked my monitor's setting that it is indeed still set to keep the aspect ratio. Indeed, going into the monitor's menu tells me that the screen still gets a 1920x1080 signal. Therefore I conclude that it's a Linux/X11/graphics driver issue.

I'm using the Nouveau driver. In Mint 13 I used the proprietary NVidia driver; that could make a difference. However I cannot imagine that there's no way to get the correct aspect ratio also with Nouveau.

Therefore my question is: What do I have to do to get 4:3 modes (or, more generally, non-16:9 modes) displayed in the correct aspect ratio on a 16:9 monitor (without affecting the 16:9 modes, obviously)?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

It turned out that it is a setting that can be changed with `xrandr`. To get back the correct aspect ratio in all modes, the following line works:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --set 'scaling mode' None
```

Here DVI-I-1 is the DVI port my monitor is connected to; that's easily found out by calling `xrandr` without options.

In order to have this run every time I log in, I've created a file `.xsessionrc` in my home directory that contains this command.

Still, this solution feels a bit like a hack; I suspect there's somewhere a configuration file where this can be set the "official" way.